# What AI model should I build to find out how similar are the 2 audio files of musical instruments like piano, guitar, synthesizer?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, audio-recognition

I have a idea for a project in AI, and I want to know how can I build such kind of AI models. I have good understanding of ML, and some beginner level understanding of Deep learning. What should I learn in order to build such projects?

I want to compare 2 audio files, of musical instruments being recorded. I want my model to tell, what differences are there in these 2 music/songs. Differences like in reverb, and delay, instruments played in wrong key, improper mixing/mastering, different waveforms in oscillators, improper automation, wrong ADSR values, etc.

One of these file will be upload by me, and other will be uploaded by the user/student. And then, my AI model will tell the student what should be improved in his/her music to be able to sound like mine.

Comment: this is an open-ended question as there can be many different but valid approaches to take.

Comment: feature extraction for audio/music is itself a whole area of signal processing. For example there is no definite algorithm to know which and how many instruments are being played (although there are approaches that tackle part of this problem). Automatic music transcription (in other wiords determining the key of the song) is another area of active research in itself. So this is a very ambitious project exceopt being open-ended question

Comment: Do you want to tell just *how* different they are, or *what* the differences are? Second one is a very hard problem

Comment: Are the two audio clips supposed to be the same song?

Comment: @junnor I want to know what changes does the student's musical parameters needed to match with mine. They aren't supposed to be a song on their own. They could be just a few seconds of riff (just a few notes of musical pattern on a synth or a piano). The idea is to have a proper understanding of the usage of the parameters in the synth.

Comment: @NikosM. There will be only one instrument in the audio clip. It could be a synth or an acoustic instrument. There will be only a couple of musical parameters being trained through a single file. It'd be great if you could give me some lead from here.